# Should we [dup]-hammer this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The [dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dup) tag is not very consistent; it is used for the Ruby method dup, the OS function dup and other unrelated things. Also it has no description.

Even the two most voted posts on the tag are not consistent:

- [What's the difference between Ruby's dup and clone methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10183370/1743880) which uses this tag for the Ruby method `dup`.
- [practical examples use dup or dup2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1720535/1743880) which uses this tag for the OS function `dup`.

There are currently 99 questions tagged with it. It has no followers.

Comment: The dupe dup tag.

Comment: [tag:dup2] has a pretty specific tag wiki that says it has to do with the system call. I would recommend a cleanup, but I'm not convinced that it needs to be burned.

Comment: dump the [dup]?

Comment: De-dup the [dup]?

Comment: Yes, that would be super dee-[dup]er !

Comment: I think it's important that this tag receives [due p]rocess.

Comment: @Anders so do you, me & dupree

Comment: Since this question was asked, a tag wiki has been added that aligns this tag with the OS function (C system call).  And it is up to 157 questions.

Comment: I've updated the `dup2()` tag to indicate that it should probably be used for questions about `dup()` too — pun mostly intentional (sorry!).  I'd like to get the questions about either system call mapped to [tag:dup2] tag over time.  I'm not sure what to do with the Ruby-based questions; I'm tempted to remove the [tag:dup] tag from them, but I don't program in Ruby.